# Market Cap: $Infinity

Tags: solidity, decentralized-exchange

What can cause this to happen on poocoin?, Market Cap: $Infinity

I have been trying to deploy an erc20 token and the deployment was successful but on poocoin, after adding liquiduty, it shows Market Cap: $Infinity

Comment: Where are seeing that cap? In the bscscan page it is showing a finite number.